# I am struggling to make incorporate google maps into android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm still learning the ins and outs of android programming.
My app shuts down immediately every time
I have gone through walkthrough after walkthrough

Can someone help me out?

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>    
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="keyvaluehere"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java
    package com.example.hellomap;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/maps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

so yeah

Comment: Gotta set up your key playa. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2 - Get an Android certificate and the Google Maps API key

Comment: Maybe I am doing this wrong?  I edited out the key I got from google console in the manifest file.  where it says 'keyvaluehere' is actually a bunch of numbers and letters

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that part of the code in your manifest. Must have skipped over it :P Anyway, that wasn't what was causing your crash, can you post your log as to what the error actually is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced similar issues with Map Fragments crashing my app. The way I resolved the crashing was to initialize the map fragment in Java rather than in xml. More specifically, I used a FrameLayout container in the xml for the map and handled all of the fragmentation in Java using FragmentManager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

...

```
import android.gms.maps;
import android.gms.maps.model;
```

...

```
MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map");
if(mapFrag == null){
   FragmentTransaction fragTran = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
   mapFrag = MapFragment.NewInstance();
   fragTran.Add(Resource.Id.map, mapFrag, "map");
   fragTran.Commit();
}
GoogleMap googleMap = mapFrag.Map;
```